# How to fetch user's likes and comments for my app posts to facebook timeline?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working on iOS app in which i have implemented Facebook integration.In the app user can login 
from Facebook ,share app events on his/her timeline.

Whenever a user posts something on the app and it goes to his/ her Facebook timeline, then I want to fetch likes and comment 
on this this particular post from Facebook.

I have gone through Facebook documentation, but I have not found any solution for this.

I want to know how could we do this, please suggest me any example or mention any official documentation of Facebook which specifies this functionality.

Help is appreciated!